# Управление приложением на android устройстве с помощью пульта от телевизора

Tags: android

Есть устройство на базе андроид (istick или tv box ) на котором установлено приложение, это устройство подключено к телевизору. Можно ли добиться того, чтобы этим приложением можно было управлять с помощью пульта от телевизора?

На сайте андроида я нашел примеры и кое какую информацию по этому поводу, но, как я понял, работает это только на телевизорах с ОС Android. 
Буду благодарен любой инфе по данному вопросу, спасибо!

Comment: То есть на данный момент у вас нет тв-приставки и вы только обдумываете возможность её покупки?

Comment: @oceinic, На данный момент нет, купить приставку не проблема, главный вопрос - будет ли эта схема работать :)

Comment: Задача очень не тривиальная. Получить представление о том, как может выглядеть процесс разработки такого приложения можно почитав http://projecturc.blogspot.ru/

Answer (score 1):

1. ИК-порт есть всего в нескольких процентах устройств. По сути, Вам придется купить для этой задачи определенную модель телефона
2. Даже если у Вас будет телефон с ИК-портом, он всё равно может быть несовместим с Вашим пультом, если окажется что тот работает в радио-диапазоне. Или если окажется, что порт работает только на передачу данных
3. Более традиционное решение - блютуз клавиатура - скорее всего обойдется дешевле покупки нового смартфона
4. Даже если у Вас появится подходящее оборудование, писать приложение придется самому. Я интересовался этим вопросом и готовых приложений с подобной функциональностью не видел
5. Даже если у Вас всё получится, пользоваться такой комбинацией вряд-ли будет удобно

Comment: Разве TV BOXы не имеют ИК портов?:) Меня именно этот момент интересует, если подключить этот самый TV BOX к телевизору, установить на него приложение, можно ли настроить это все так, чтобы управлять это все пультом от телевизора.

Comment: Даже если и имеют, не факт что этот порт будет доступен через Android API